# Windows 10 HDMI video lag, no sound

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, hdmi

I have this issue with Windows 10. I have used the same setup with Windows 8.1 without any problems.

The first thing I've noticed, is that there is no sound over HDMI. I'm using a Philips 5500 series TV (fully HDCP compliant). When connected, it is properly recognized—the audio output is set to default, but there is no sound.

The second problem is, when I am playing videos (like YouTube), the playback is lagging, until I disconnect the HDMI cable.

Computer specifications:

- Machine: Lenovo Y50-70
- CPU: Intel i7-4710HQ
- RAM: 12 GB
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX860M 4GB Maxwell, Intel HD 4600
- OS: Windows 10 Pro

As far as I know, it has the latest drivers.

Comment: See posts 15 and 17 here. https://communities.intel.com/thread/77889?start=15&tstart=0 Basically uninstalling and disabling Hyper-V might fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved the same issue thanks to [this thread](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=146911).

Get the latest Intel video/audio drivers and update the Intel Management Engine. The Intel Management Engine update solved this problem (latest updates of video drivers didn't change anything). It seems that it's a problem with the HDCP/DRM codecs which are provided with the Intel Management Engine.

Comment: In my case, the Intel Management Engine driver is installed, but the problem is still there.

Comment: I have the same issue on a Surface Pro 3. Reinstalled all the Intel Video drivers, uninstalled the Management Engine and have Windows Update download the latest driver again, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling hyper-v, if its installed.

I had the same problem, with Intel HD4600 and windows 10 on MSI Ghost Pro, tried all 3 available Intel display audio driver versions at the time and nothing helped, i could see thous green sound bars show up, but no sound, until I uninstalled hyper-v from my windows 10.

more details:
https://communities.intel.com/thread/77889?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

YES!, I solve this problem, and wish you all can.

- right click the speakers select playback devices.
- right click your default device select test. (will show active level with green level line but no sound).
- right click again to select disable.
- right click again to select enable.

if this not works, try set speakers by default device and than set your hdmi by default device. hope this can work.

Comment: What hardware configuration do you have?
On MS SP3 with Windows 10 it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I am still using my laptop with Intel HD Graphics 4600 and experienced no sound issues on HDMI after enabling virtual machine platform in Windows 10 - I have tried different [drivers](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/18369/intel-graphics-driver-for-windows-15-40.html) without stable results. But after disabling the virtual machine platform it worked again:

```
dism.exe /online /disable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform
```